# virtualenv Env not creating bin directory in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I'm a newbie to Python and I've spent hours on this. I can't seem to figure out why when I run a simple command to setup my Python environment: `virtualenv --distribute env`

This doesn't create a bin file in the `env` directory.

It only creates:

```
-- env
   -- Include
   -- Lib
   -- Scripts
```

My impressions was that a bin directory would be created per a lot of the examples I've found on the web (e.g. I'm not able to run this command: `env/bin/activate`).

I'm using Windows 7 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 100):

On Windows, this is entirely correct. A `bin` directory is created on POSIX systems only. From the [Windows Notes](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html?highlight=windows#windows-notes) section of the documentation:

> Some paths within the virtualenv are slightly different on Windows: scripts and executables on Windows go in `ENV\Scripts\` instead of `ENV/bin/` and libraries go in `ENV\Lib\` rather than `ENV/lib/`.

For Windows, run `\path\to\env\Scripts\activate` to activate the virtualenv. From the [documentation](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/virtualenv.html#activate-script) again:

> On Windows you just do:
>
> `> \path\to\env\Scripts\activate`
>
> And type *deactivate* to undo the changes.
>
> Based on your active shell (CMD.exe or Powershell.exe), Windows will use either `activate.bat` or `activate.ps1` (as appropriate) to activate the virtual environment.

Comment: Wow... thansk for the super fast response. This has been driving me crazy. Makes it hard to follow examples on the web if this type of thing doesn't match.

Comment: Most examples make the assumption you are using a POSIX (e.g. Linux or Mac) system.

Comment: What about people using bash shells on windows? Eg Cygwin, MinGw, MySysGit, what are these folks to do?

Comment: As far as I understand--and I barely understand it--you need to execute the `activate.bat` file, *not* the `activate` file, which is in the same directory.

Comment: @aliteralmind on windows the `.bat` extension is implied. No shell scripts are created on windows. E.g. When running `activate` the file with extension is found and exectuted, and there is no file by that name without an extension in the `Scripts` directory anyway.

Comment: There is both an `activate` and  `activate.bat` file in my `Scripts` directory.

Comment: @aliteralmind: ah, yes, there is a shell file there too, for Cygwin, I see. But IIRC that file is ignored and the `.bat` is used. Then again, the docs I reference could predate the Cygwin support and that may no longer be true.

Comment: @aliteralmind: the current documentation still states that `CMD.exe` will use `activate.bat` and Powershell will use `activate.ps1` when you do this. Is your experience different?

Comment: Running `activate.bat` works. I was confused because I'm watching a Linux based tutorial, which tells you to execute `bin/activate`. If you look in the no-extension `activate` file, it says `# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*`, `# you cannot run it directly`. I don't know how to do that. But the point's moot, as the bat file works.

Comment: @aliteralmind: yes, but so will `Scripts\activate` as your console will then use `activate.bat`, *not* the shell script.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Really nice and answer is to the point explains in details

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Git Bash for Windows, I found the following command works to activate the environment: $ source (path to environment)/Scripts/activate

I was using Git Bash on Windows 10, Python(v3.7), Pip (v19.0.3), virtualenv (v16.4.3)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, correct. On Windows, it creates the directory hierarchy as follows:

- venv (virtual environment name)

  - Include
  - Lib\site-packages
  - Scripts

Just like in this image:

[image: obnoxious screen shot].

Comment: What is the new thing you added?

Answer (score -1):

For windows , you have to run `python -m venv <your_env_name>` and
`source <your_env_name>/Scripts/acivate`.
This works for me on windows.

Comment: `source` is a Linux bash command. You might have used git bash on Windows at that moment, and then you should write this as well, and it would be a copy of another answer anyway. Downvote.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to point your IDE to the python.exe of your virtual env in Windows, its under the /scripts folder.