# including external python libraries when uploading python files to github

Tags: python, github, libraries

So I wrote some code in python that used the requests library. I am thinking of uploading the files onto github so other people can test out the file. Uploading the main is easy (just one .py) file, but how do I include the requests library?

Is there a way for me to also the requests library along with my .py file so they can immediately run the python file ? or should I tell them to also install requests through pip first?

Comment: you can install external libraries in a virtual environment and upload your environment folder.

Comment: interesting suggestion. Are there any guides on how to do that?? thanks!

Comment: guide of which topic?

Comment: I guess both install external libraries in a virtual environment and then uploading it

Comment: No, if you are familiar with `virtual environment`, `pip`, `git` you can do it. :)

Comment: yeah I found the link and am currently playing with it :) thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have a folder which you have initialized with `git`. Now form go to that directory and create a virtual environment by the command,

```
virtualenv env
```

activate the virtual environment by the command,

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Now install external libraries in it with `pip`.

```
pip install requests
```

Yor python file `my.py` will be in the same folder where you initialized `git` using `git init`.
structure will be like,

```
project
|----env
|    |----bin
|    |----include
|    |----lib
|    |----local
|----my.py
```

Now you can push the contents of the projcet in your repository with necessary libraries installed in a virtual environment.

Comment: Hi, not sure if I am doing this right or nt, but there is no env folder in my project folder. What I have is Include, lib, and Scripts

Comment: what process did you follow?

Comment: I first installed virtualenv using pip, then I call python -m virtualenv venv. In my newly created venv folder on my desktop, I see Include, Lib, and Scripts

Comment: create the virtual environment in your the folder that you are going to push in `git`. follow the instructions in my answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206990/virtualenv-env-not-creating-bin-directory-in-windows-7 found the solution!

Comment: Yeah off-course. you are on windows machine. my bad. :)