# virtualenv Env not creating Scripts directory in Windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I seem to have the opposite issue of this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13206990/1814739). Somehow every time I create a virtual environment it is creating the POSIX setup instead of Windows.

So I am running the below command in Windows 7:

```
virtualenv venv
```

And I get the wrong dir structure (POSIX):

```
-venv
  -bin
  -include
  -lib
```

How do I fix this? Is there a virtualenv option or a config somewhere I can adjust? I would like it to create:

```
 -venv
   -Include
   -Lib
   -Scripts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe the issue is with running commands from Cygwin terminal. I reran this command from powershell:

```
C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\ez_setup.py
```

Then ran:

```
easy_install.exe virtualenv
```

Note the .exe this time.. now when I run:

```
virtualenv.exe someDir
```

I get the Windows directory structure. Running:

```
virtualenv someDir
```

Will create the POSIX directories.